# Matrix Not Displaying Front End

Tags: matrix

Can you please help. Matrix isn't displaying information on the front end.
http://www.ledgrouprobus.com/robus

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are not showing us your code, that's what. It's close to impossible to debug from just the front end, as we can't trouble shoot your pre-parsed code. Just the snippets that count please :0)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, what code do you need to see? Excuse my EE noobness!

Comment: Show us the relevant bit in your template. Someone will be able to point you in the right direction from there. ;)